# Testing with in-memory NServiceBus

Tags: testing, rabbitmq, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I'm attempting to create a high level test in my solution, and I want to 'catch' messages sent to the bus.

Here's what I do:

1. nUnit [SetUp] spins up the WebAPI project in IISExpress
2. SetUp also creates the bus
3. Send  a HTTP request to the API
4. Verify whatever I want to verify

The WebAPI part of the whole test works fine. The creation of the bus and kicking it off seems great too. It even finds my fake message handler. The problem is the handler never receives the command from the queue, they just stay in the RabbitMQ queue forever.

Here's how the bus is being configured:

```
var bus = Configure.With()
                   .DefineEndpointName("Local")
                   .Log4Net()
                   .UseTransport<global::NServiceBus.RabbitMQ>()
                   .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
                   .RijndaelEncryptionService()
                   .UnicastBus();
                   .CreateBus();
```

In the log from NServiceBus starting up, I see that my fake handler is being associated with the command:

```
2014-09-24 15:29:59,007 [Runner thread] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry 
[(null)] <(null)> - Associated 'Bloo.MyCommand' message with 'Blah.FakeMyCommandHandler' handler
```

So seeing as the message lands in the correct RabbitMQ queue, I'm assuming everything up until the handler point is working fine.

I've tried putting waits in my [TearDown] so that the bus lives a little longer - hoping to give the handler time to receive the message. I've also tried spinning off the in-memory bus for the consumer part of the interactoin into a new thread with no luck.

Has anyone else tried this?

This is only the first step, what I would love to do is create a fake bus that records messages being sent to it. The need for RabbitMQ is just to get myself going (the bounds of my solution are WebAPI on the front and the bus at the back).

Cheers

Comment: Are you calling .Start() on the bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your messages are just sitting in your queue forever because your end point is listening on "Local.MachineName" queue instead of "Local"

If you set the ScaleOut to be SingleBrokerQueue this should sort the issue.

```
Configure.ScaleOut(s => s.UseSingleBrokerQueue());

var bus = Configure.With()
               .DefineEndpointName("Local")
               ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call .Start() on the bus, that's why it didn't listen for messages.

See here for more info: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process-v4.x

Also, consider using NServiceBus.Testing for unit testing your handlers and sagas:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Testing

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to do full integration tests, using actual queues, then this answer won't help you.

If you are doing more focused tests, i.e. testing individual components that rely on the bus, I would recommend that you use a mocking framework (I like Moq) and mock out IBus.  You can then verify that messages you expected to be sent to the bus were indeed sent.